# Laravel 5.5 - how to mock eloquent database collection

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, collections, eloquent, mocking

I've decided to make some unit tests for my app and I have a problem.

I have logic part

```
private $model;
__construct($model)
{
    $this->model = $model;
}

public function getData()
{
    $data = $this->model->getData();
    return $data;
}
```

model

```
public function $getData()
{
    return self::where('id', '=', 1)->first();
}
```

and now I would like to make unit test.
I know how to mock right model

```
$collection = new Collection();
$collection->push(
    new Model(

    )
);
```

but have no idea how to put data into it. I've tried put data as attribute but it throws me MassAssigmentException

Would be grateful if someone know and share his knowledge.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding

Comment: I want to prepare unit test. Separate from datebase. Also i don't think it would be good to have 1000 units where every one migrates and seeds testing datebase. I want to have whole pack of tests done in minute, not in 2 hours.

Comment: OK, my bad. I needed just to prepare model and push it into collection.